# RxJs: shareReplay() with cache invalidation after time

Tags: rxjs

I want my shareReplay() to keep the value of a HttpService call (`wsCall()`) for a specific period of time. I often see samples like this on the web:

```
interval(10000).pipe(
    startWith(null),
    switchMap(_ => wsCall()),
    shareReplay()
);
```

The problem here is, that the webservice is called again every 10 seconds even if the Observable has no subscribers! Thats the internal behavior of shareReplay() - it subscribes and forwards the results.

But how to (easily) achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the underlying `share` operator instead of `shareReplay`

```js
interval(10000).pipe(
    startWith(null),
    switchMap(_ => wsCall()),
    share({
      connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
      // this next line causes it to stop the interval if
      // no one is subscribed for more than 5 seconds
      resetOnRefCountZero: () => timer(5_000),
      resetOnError: false,
      resetOnComplete: false,
   }),
);
```

Comment: Just perfect, thank you!

Comment: No, it somehow isn't working, yet. It looked pretty good to me, but the `resetOnRefCountZero` factory isn't called. Any idea? I was trying it a bit more simplified:

Comment: wsCall().pipe(share({
 connector: () => new ReplaySubject(),
 resetOnRefCountZero: () => timer(5_000),
 resetOnComplete: false,
 resetOnError: false
}))

Comment: I needed to use resetOnComplete instead! But sure that's the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: I'd need to see your usage in context.  resetOnComplete won't have any effect here because intervals never complete.  resetOnRefCountZero is the only thing that will have effect here.  And it only triggers if all of your observers have unsubscribed.  Ah your new (in comment) example is not using interval.  Yes, resetOnComplete would be useful in that case